# Will an UPDATE statement with a range predicate "prefer" non-locked rows

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-5.7

Given a table called `workers` and a schema with columns `leaderId`, `lastUpdated`. When  multiple DB connections are running this `UPDATE` statement, will the non-locked rows that meet the predicate (`WHERE` clause) be considered for update *first* or will the query block on a matching row that is locked? If the unlocked are not considered first, is there a way to do that?

```
BEGIN
UPDATE workers SET leaderId = ?, lastUpdated = NOW(6) 
WHERE lastUpdated IS NULL OR lastUpdated < DATE_SUB(NOW(6),INTERVAL 3 SECOND)
LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM workers WHERE leaderId = ?;
COMMIT
```

Comment: mysql8.0 has a [skip locked](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) as part of its `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` syntax. Its not available in MySQL-5.7 however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

All or none.  That is the prime mandate of InnoDB "transactions".  Your `BEGIN`...`COMMIT` controls the range of the transaction.

`DATE_SUB(NOW(6),INTERVAL 3 SECOND)` and `NOW(6)` will be calculated once, at the beginning of the `UPDATE` statement.

You have `LIMIT 1` without an `ORDER BY`.  That means that you cannot predict which 1 row will be picked.  However, the Optimizer will not pick a row based on anything other than how fast it can perform the query, *without regard for what might be locked*.

It looks like you are implementing a "queue"?  The `UPDATE` 'grabs' one row, then the `SELECT` gets the data in that row?

`OR` optimizes poorly.  In general no index is useful, so the `UPDATE` will scan the entire table in some convenient order, stopping when it finds one or the other condition met.

The usual optimization for `OR` is to break it into two queries.  The probably means changing your overall logic to have the main code grab a `NULL`.  And have a separate "reaper" process that runs around grabbing any "old" items (that were presumably orphaned due to a worker crash).

(I hesitate to suggest a rewrite, because I don't fully understand your logic.  I would expect the table `queue` to be acted on, not `workers`.  So, please explain your code.  I may have other tips.)